# Changing all the same strings with a user input

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a registry file creator for the game *The Sims 3*, as originally it's in Russian.

What I would like to do is change **all** relative parameters to what the user selects.

The [reg file](https://pastebin.com/EnDX8YzV) has multiple "RU" strings, same for "ru-RU" and execution path (C:\Users\Lollo\Desktop\Nuova cartella\The Sims 3.Gold Edition.v 21.0.150 + Store\).

This is the code I am using to replace the strings:

```
Dim replacetext As String = TextBox1.Text

If RichTextBox1.SelectedText.Length <= 0 Then

    Exit Sub

End If

Dim s As String = "RU"

Dim nextPos As Integer

nextPos = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(RichTextBox1.SelectedText)

While ((nextPos < RichTextBox1.Text.Length) And (nextPos >= 0))

    RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = nextPos

    RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = s.Length

    RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(s, replacetext)

    nextPos = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(s, nextPos + 1)

End While
```

However it's not working.

This is how my GUI is presented to the user:

[image: GUI]

Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it the way you're approaching it, I would rather suggest using string.replace and replacing with your values.

It would look a little something like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = Textbox1.Text
.Replace("ru-RU",ComboBox2.Text)
.Replace("RU",ComboBox3.Text)
```

I don't have all the detail so doing it fully is difficult, but the way you seem to be wanting may be a bit long winded.

Another suggestion is to just use Regex and replace that way.

Edit:

Ignoring case, slightly more risky.

```
TextBox1.Text = Textbox1.Text
.ToLower()
.Replace("ru-ru",ComboBox2.Text)
.Replace("ru",ComboBox3.Text)
```

Comment: ok, i've used this code:

https://pastebin.com/aPHtK2vy

I got a problem with the "ru-RU" thing, it changes only the uppercase letters and not the lowercase, any tips?

Comment: EDIT: Just relooked at the snippet, please do the ru-RU replace first and then the RU replace. Thanks

Comment: worked as a charm. Now if i wanna export all the edited code into a txt file? any help?

Comment: @VanillaRainbow that's not how it works round here. Accept this as the answer (tick to the left) and go about looking into exporting to a text file. There are loads of examples on SO and you can Google too.

Comment: As @Bugs says, look around on SO first, and if you still can't figure it out show us what you have tried and someone will help you, but If I kept chaining answers, it would be confusing for someone coming with a similar question.

Comment: Hi @VanillaRainbow if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.